# Join lists without redundant elements in a list [python]

Tags: python

I'm having this error when trying to remove topics in a List[Tuple[Union[bytes, str], Union[dict, dict]]]

Here a sample of the list:

```
 analyzed_comments = [('setup.py', {'Topic_0': ['version', 'get'], 'Topic_1': ['version', 'get']}), 
    ('translation.py', {'Topic_0': ['multiline', 'pattern', 'skip'], 'Topic_1': ['multiline', 'concat', 'text']})]
```

I would like to have a resulting list that stores:

- name of the file
- list of non redundant topics

Something like:

```
comment_topics = [('setup.py', ['version', 'get']), 
                    ('translation.py', ['multiline', 'pattern', 'skip', 'concat', 'text'])]
```

This is what I wrote, but it doesn't seem to do this job well:

```
comment_topics = list()
temp_comments = list()
for file, comment in analyzed_comments:
    for topic in comment:
        elem = body[topic]
        temp_comments = list(set(elem + temp_comments))

    tupla = (file, temp_comments)
    comment_topics.append(tupla)
print(comment_topics)
```

have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea would be to iterate over the files and simply combine all topics. In the end we create a set from the topics to remove all duplicates:

```
bodies = [('setup.py', {'Topic_0': ['version', 'get'], 'Topic_1': ['version', 'get']}), 
    ('translation.py', {'Topic_0': ['multiline', 'pattern', 'skip'], 'Topic_1': ['multiline', 'concat', 'text']})]


result = {}
for x in bodies:
    values = []
    for v in x[1].values():
        values.extend(v)
    result[x[0]] = list(set(values))
    
result
```

Output:

```
{'setup.py': ['version', 'get'],
 'translation.py': ['multiline', 'pattern', 'text', 'skip', 'concat']}
```

You can also do it in one line:

```
{k: list(set(sum(v.values(),[]))) for k, v in bodies}
```

or with `itertools` which should be faster than `sum()` in most cases:

```
import itertools
result = {k: list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(v.values()))) for k, v in bodies}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't really understand the onliner tho, which one of them is better/more efficient? Because I work on very large datasets

Comment: You're welcome.  The onliner uses `sum()` instead of the inner loop with `extend()`, which is not even faster regarding [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45323085/7947994).  The outer part in the oneliner is a generator, which has lazy evaluation (good for large datasets) but is not necessarily faster. I would start with the first option as it is more understandable and optimize from there if it is not fast enough. Your problem can be optimized as each operation on a row is independent from all other rows.

Comment: Had another lool and added a third option. Using a generator is probably not a bad idea if your dataset is large. The performance also varies depending on how many topics each row has and so on. I would simply test the solutions with your dataset and take the fastest one.